# How to store the argument of a function to use in inner functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following kind of code in NodeJS (Typescript):

```
private grandMotherFunction(arg1: MyObject, arg2: any){
...
aClass.motherFunction(arg1)
...

}
```

and the aClass.motherFunction looks like this:

```
private motherFunction(arg1: MyObject){
...
otherClass.childFunction(arg1,otherArgument)
...

}
```

and the otherClass.childFunction looks like this:

```
private childFunction(arg1: MyObject, arg2: any){
...
someOtherClass.grandChildFunction(arg1, somethingMore)
...

}
```

and the code follows like this, passing the same argument to all the functions in different Classes.
The point is that the arg1:MyObject, it is only needed in the granchildFunction.
I would like to know if it would be possibe to store the argument somewhere, like in the executing Thread and then in the grandchildFunction retrieve it. 
As it is a Express App (in fact it is a Loopback 4.0), I have thought to do it in the originating request, but i don't want the last otherClass to import the Request.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a variable `arg1: MyObject` that is only being used by one function, and that function is only invoked through another one and you don't want to have to pass `arg1` through the other functions?

If so, I would maybe set that argument as `this.arg1: MyObject` and call `this.arg1` `someOtherClass.grandChildFunction`...

So you could have

```
private grandChildFunction(arg2: any){

    otherClass.grandChildFunction(this.arg1);

}
```

Comment: The problem is that the functions are in different classes so the method from  OtherClass.grandChildFunction() it hassn't the same context that the MainClass.grandMotherFunction()